# What to use to watch a video from multiple angles

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-processing, video-capture, video-player, video-editing

I am trying to create an app &/or web based online school that I am filming instruction from four different angels. I can't find anything that I could code to allow the user to select a different camera view and progress during the video.

Ideally there will be four cameras filming the exact technique but the user should be able to jump to different views throughout the video without having to start again.

I have searched online for three days now but cannot find anything to what I want/need.

I just want the video to play and the user to be able to switch to different camera views.

Comment: If you have all 4 videos can you not turn off the sound/camera for the ones you dont want, and basically (badly as this sounds) play all 4 at the same time.. or, make a note of where you are in  1 as you swap round it continues on the next?

Comment: There are multiple approaches to this, which is the best kind of depends. Are you live streaming these videos? Or downloading them all before playing them? Maybe you include the videos in your build so it doesn't have to be streamed/downloaded at all?

Comment: Hello, the videos will most likely be streaming but not live. I wanted the open to cache them to view the video for later to save on data charges

Comment: @bugfinder ideally they would be looking at one screen and then if they wish they can view the other screen buy clicking the button underneath

Comment: Then I stick with the original suggestion which is that as long as all videos are in sync, play all 4 to different "cameras" in unity and just swap cameras

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property:

```
VideoPlayer.frame
```

When the user "changes camera angle", record the frame of the currently playing video, stop it, start playing the new video from the different angle and set it's frame property to match the last video.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions I’ll try to ideas and post the progress soon.